# Hazelcast: Avoid Warning When Running a Cluster

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, hazelcast

I have this Spring-Boot 1.5.4 project that needed a clustered database cache with Hazelcast. So the changes I made are these:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast-eureka-one</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis.caches</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-hazelcast</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Bean:

```
  @Bean
  public Config hazelcastConfig(EurekaClient eurekaClient) {
    EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategyFactory.setEurekaClient(eurekaClient);

    Config config = new Config();
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    return config;
  }
```

mapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.sjngm.blah.dao.mapper.AttributeMapper">

  <resultMap type="attribute" id="attributeResult">
    ...
  </resultMap>

  <cache type="org.mybatis.caches.hazelcast.HazelcastCache" eviction="LRU" size="100000" flushInterval="600000" />

  ...
```

I don't have a `hazelcast.xml` or `eureka-client.properties`.

It starts fine, but logs this:

```
2019-11-13 09:51:48,003 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2019-11-13 09:51:48,005 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Finished creating instance of bean 'hazelcastConfig'
2019-11-13 09:51:48,005 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Autowiring by type from bean name 'hazelcastInstance' via factory method to bean named 'hazelcastConfig'
2019-11-13 09:51:48,066 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker] [localhost-startStop-1] [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2019-11-13 09:51:48,124 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker] [localhost-startStop-1] [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Picked [10.20.20.86]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2019-11-13 09:51:48,142 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Hazelcast 3.7.7 (20170404 - e3c56ea) starting at [10.20.20.86]:5701
2019-11-13 09:51:48,142 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2019-11-13 09:51:48,142 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2019-11-13 09:51:48,341 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Backpressure is disabled
2019-11-13 09:51:49,006 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 4 partition threads
2019-11-13 09:51:49,008 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2019-11-13 09:51:49,013 INFO  [com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] [10.20.20.86]:5701 is STARTING
2019-11-13 09:51:49,014 INFO  [com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2019-11-13 09:51:49,031 WARN  [com.hazelcast.instance.Node] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
2019-11-13 09:51:49,063 INFO  [com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] [localhost-startStop-1] [10.20.20.86]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] [10.20.20.86]:5701 is STARTED
2019-11-13 09:51:49,269 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Eagerly caching bean 'hazelcastInstance' to allow for resolving potential circular references
...
2019-11-13 09:51:50,563 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] [main] Registered type handler: 'class [C'
2019-11-13 09:51:50,563 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] [main] Registered type handler: 'class java.time.Duration'
2019-11-13 09:51:50,563 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] [main] Registered type handler: 'class java.net.URL'
2019-11-13 09:51:50,563 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] [main] Registered type handler: 'class java.time.ZonedDateTime'
2019-11-13 09:51:50,655 INFO  [com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator] [main] Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
2019-11-13 09:51:50,812 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker] [main] [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2019-11-13 09:51:50,867 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker] [main] [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.7] Picked [10.20.20.86]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
2019-11-13 09:51:50,868 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Hazelcast 3.7.7 (20170404 - e3c56ea) starting at [10.20.20.86]:5702
2019-11-13 09:51:50,868 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2019-11-13 09:51:50,868 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2019-11-13 09:51:50,873 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Backpressure is disabled
2019-11-13 09:51:51,010 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.Node] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Creating MulticastJoiner
2019-11-13 09:51:51,019 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 4 partition threads
2019-11-13 09:51:51,020 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Starting 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2019-11-13 09:51:51,020 INFO  [com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] [10.20.20.86]:5702 is STARTING
2019-11-13 09:51:51,021 INFO  [com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
2019-11-13 09:51:53,952 INFO  [com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] 


Members [1] {
    Member [10.20.20.86]:5702 - d29f6be8-a775-4804-bce3-8e0d3aaaab4b this
}

2019-11-13 09:51:53,953 WARN  [com.hazelcast.instance.Node] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied!
2019-11-13 09:51:53,954 INFO  [com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] [main] [10.20.20.86]:5702 [dev] [3.7.7] [10.20.20.86]:5702 is STARTED
2019-11-13 09:51:50,917 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] [main] Parsed mapper file: 'file [C:\workspaces\projects\com.sjngm.blah.db\target\classes\sqlmap\AttributeMapper.xml]'
```

It logs the two warnings and I don't know why. At first it tries to instantiate a standalone instance and then it plays along and uses Eureka and "complains" about the opened port 5701.

IMHO the first block shouldn't be there at all, which would result in the second warning not being printed. It looks like Hazelcast initialises itself at first and then Spring-Boot creates the `@Bean`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you disabled multicast, you have no joiner for Hazelcast. That is why it prints

> No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-eureka#java-based-configuration) how to enable it for Eureka

For older versions like 3.7, you can use  to configure Eureka by giving fully qualified class name.

```
<network>
<discovery-strategies>
  <discovery-strategy class="com.hazelcast.eureka.one.EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategy" enabled="true">
    <properties>
      <property name="namespace">hazelcast</property>
    </properties>
  </discovery-strategy>
</discovery-strategies>
</network>
```

P.S: I suggest you to upgrade to latest hazelcast as 3.7.7 is pretty old. 
Latest Hazelcast Versions are listed here. https://hazelcast.org/download/

Comment: I'm tied to Spring-Boot 1.5.4 and all its dependencies. Too bad `getEurekaConfig()` didn't exist back then.

Comment: You can use generic DiscoveryStrategy configuration. It supports EurekaConfig

Comment: I don't understand. There is no class `EurekaConfig`.

Comment: EurekaConfig is an example simplified version to some well known Service Discovery Options. Please see 3.7 documentation with the section "Configuring DiscoveryStrategy" https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/

You can use XML configuration there to configure Eureka for older versions. I am updating my answer too

Comment: Oh, thanks. This way and without my `@Bean`-method it asks for `eureka-client.properties`, which I guess means it can't find the Eureka-client. Where/how do I call `EurekaOneDiscoveryStrategyFactory.setEurekaClient(eurekaClient);` now?

Comment: there are some programming configuration in an old fashioned way in old github issues. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-eureka/issues/28 That can give some idea I guess.

Comment: Yeah, in the meantime I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54460282/483113) answer that also replaces the XML and the first warning is now gone (basically set "hazelcast.discovery.enabled" to `true`). So I'm still wondering why it tries to generate a second port.

Comment: Well, let's say Mybatis does that itself and it knows what it's doing. I mean I tried something with two instances of my web-service and that worked.